# Anime where people summon monsters using gun-like devices that carve patterns in the air

Tags: story-identification, anime

I watched this anime where each person summoned one monster with this device that was kind of gun-like. They would weave (or cut) signs into the air to make their monster perform a special attack.

If their monster died, the summoner would lose their memory from the point that they made the contract. When the monsters were summoned, they would be walking among paper doors from Japan.

The main character had this blue cat-man character that had a sword. This cat-man apparently was in the manga as well apparently. Also, I think the cat-man was voiced by the Japanese voice actor for Edward Elric in *Fullmetal Alchemist*.

The main character's summoned monster is a white tiger anthropomorphic character and I remember his sword being a big deal. Like they had to find a sign in order to make his sword bigger or something like that.

I watched this anime around the late 2000s or early 2010s. We had to find it on non-mainstream sites and I don't think it was ever dubbed, so it had a very Japanese name. Does anyone know what this anime is called and maybe a site where I could watch it?

Answer (score 5):

It's Onmyō Taisenki.

People have summon monsters and the device they use starts as kind of a disc and they flip it into a gun shape device. Haven't found a site to watch it yet, but it took me hours of different variations of "Anime Monster tamer with white tiger anthropomorphic character." Oh, and there are a few other characters with summons of their own. One is a giant black tiger thing, there is a bird guy, and this cool blue dragon type guy. Man i'm looking forward to watching this again.

Comment: You can (and should) accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting button, as per the [tour]. Self-accepts can't be done before 48 hours after the question was asked, but attempting to accept early tells you how much time you have left. Congrats!

Answer (score 1):

Could this be the anime adaptation of the video game ***[Shin Megami Tensei: Devil Children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shin_Megami_Tensei:_Devil_Children)*** (2000-2001)...?

> *Shin Megami Tensei: Devil Children*,[a] also known as *DemiKids*, is a series of role-playing video games primarily developed by Multimedia Intelligence Transfer and published by Atlus. It is a spin-off from Atlus' *Megami Tensei* franchise, and began in 2000 with the Game Boy Color games *Black Book* and *Red Book*. Five more role-playing games and three games in other genres were released until 2004, followed by no new releases until the 2011 social game *Shin Megami Tensei: Devil Children*. In addition to the games, the series has been adapted into manga, anime, and a trading card game, and two soundtrack albums have been released by First Smile Entertainment.
>
> The series follows demon-human hybrids called devil children, who journey from Japan to the demon world, and are joined by talking companion monsters who give them guidance. The player takes the role of one such devil child, and battles against demons; the devil children do not fight directly themselves, however, but have allied demons in their party fight for them. The player can choose to talk to demons instead of fighting them, to try to make them join the player's party, and can increase their allied demons' power by fusing multiple demons with each other.

The first episode of the follow-up series, *[Shin Megami Tensei Devil Children: Light & Dark](https://myanimelist.net/anime/4068/Shin_Megami_Tensei_Devil_Children__Light___Dark)*, is up on YouTube, and includes a scene where two boys summon creatures using gun-like devices called Devilizers, which project circular portals in midair with symbols on them, from which the creatures emerge. These devices are also present in the original series.

Comment: No, i am aware of Shin Megami. Though thanks for that drop, you just reminded me of another anime i forgot about.

Comment: Also, i think the cat-man mon was voiced by the same guy that did Edward Elric in Full Metal Alchemist Japanese voice.

Comment: The main character's summoned monster is a white tiger anamorphic character and i remember his sword being a big deal. Like they had to find a sign in order to make his sword bigger or something like that.